# Using XP mode on Windows 7, 64-bit or 32-bit?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, virtualization

If I am virtualizing Windows XP using Windows Virtual PC on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine, can I run 64-bit software through the virtualization?

Comment: It is quite a common dev platform setup, tho?

Comment: My understanding of Windows XP mode in Windows 7 is that it is a 32-bit only OS.

Answer (score 8):

No.  Windows Virtual PC will only support 32-bit Operating Systems.  This is also the case for Windows XP Mode.

Answer (score 1):

From `MSINFO32` on XP in Virtual PC:

```
OS Name Microsoft Windows XP Professional
Version 5.1.2600 Service Pack 3 Build 2600
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
System Model    Virtual Machine
System Type X86-based PC
Processor   x86 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10 GenuineIntel ~2067 Mhz
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows XP Mode is strictly the name of a special version of XP that you can download and run. This is 32 bit. On top of this, Microsoft Virtual PC only has the ability to run x86/32-bit guests.

If you actually want to install Windows from a source and not use XP Mode, you can use [VMWare Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) or [Sun Virtual Box](http://www.virtualbox.org) (both free) or [VMware Workstation](http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/) to install a x64/64-bit guest operating system.